# excel vba IE Object

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get results from this page https://search.rpxcorp.com/advanced_search/search_litigations#grouped=false&searchq=%221%3A2015-cv-00014%22&page=1&sub_page=1

But getting error:

[image: got this popup]

After clicking Debug when I moved my cursor to the "ObjResult5" it says ObjResult5 = "Nothing"

[image: got this popup]

My macro:

```
Sub getDataIE_Basic()
Dim totalResults As Long
Dim RowBasic As Long
totalResults = 2-1
RowBasic = 2

Set Sheet_OutputBasic = Worksheets("Output - Basic Data")
Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIEBrowser.Visible = True
Dim url As String
url = "https://search.rpxcorp.com/advanced_search/search_litigations#grouped=false&searchq=%221%3A2015-cv-00014%22&page=1&sub_page=1"

objIEBrowser.navigate url

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until objIEBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Call FnWait(5)

Set Doc = objIEBrowser.document

For Results = 0 To totalResults

Set objResultMain = Doc.getElementById("search_results_replaced_content")
Set objResult = objResultMain.getElementsByTagName("Div")(0)
Set objResult2 = objResult.getElementsByTagName("Div")(1)
Set objResult3 = objResult2.getElementsByTagName("Div")(2)
Set objResult4 = objResult3.getElementsByTagName("Div")(1)
Set objResult5 = objResult4.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
Set objResult6 = objResult5.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
Set objResult7 = objResult6.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)

FileDate = objResult7.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
CaseName = objResult7.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
CaseNo = objResult7.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText
FilJurisdiction = objResult7.getElementsByTagName("td")(3).innerText
Status = objResult7.getElementsByTagName("td")(4).innerText

Sheet_OutputBasic.Cells(RowBasic, 1) = FileDate
Sheet_OutputBasic.Cells(RowBasic, 2) = CaseName
Sheet_OutputBasic.Cells(RowBasic, 3) = CaseNo
Sheet_OutputBasic.Cells(RowBasic, 4) = FilJurisdiction
Sheet_OutputBasic.Cells(RowBasic, 5) = Status

RowBasic = RowBasic + 1

Next Results

End Sub
Function FnWait(intTime)

newHour = Hour(Now())

newMinute = Minute(Now())

newSecond = Second(Now()) + intTime

waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait waitTime

End Function
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `but getting errors` - super useful... **what** errors are you getting? be specific please.

Comment: it gets the objResult5 = nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at that page using the Network tab of firefox developer tools (see the image below).

The reason you get the error is because there is no `<table ...>` element when the page is first loaded. There is a second call (POST) to `search_litigations` that contains the table you are trying to access.

You will need to determine the correct call to get the data you want.

[image]